# How to convert a byte to ASCII hexadecimal representation in c++?

Tags: c++, char, byte

I just want to convert a byte to its ASCII character.

Here is the problem:

Lets suppose we have a character like below:

```
char a = 0x0b;
```

I just want to convert this to its hexadecimal ASCII character representation 'b' .

Comment: Do you want to print the numerical value of `a` in hexadecimal?

Comment: @geza Obviously.

Comment: A byte converted to an ascii character is the exact same byte.  Your conversion of `0x0b` to `b` makes no sense because it is entirely unclear what `0x1a` would need to be converted to.  So, you have a lot more explaining to do.

Comment: maybe `char r = "0123456789abcdef"[a]` do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the appropriate [I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex):

```
char a = 0x0b;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << (int)a;
    // ^^^^^^^^
char ascii = oss.str()[0];
```

See it working live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36ac3ef23a4deb4b).

---

An alternative would be to use a simple table of characters:

```
char a = 0x0b;
char ascii = "0123456789abcdef"[a];
```

To extract values bigger than `0x0f` use bit shifting and masking:

```
unsigned char a = 0xab;
const char* hexDigitTable = "0123456789abcdef";
char asciiDigit0 = hexDigitTable[a & 0x0f];
char asciiDigit1 = hexDigitTable[(a & 0xf0) >> 4];
std::cout << asciiDigit1 << asciiDigit0 << std::endl;
```

Here's the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ee963c2170778e0).

---

Note: I've been using `unsigned char` above to get rid of the compiler warning on initialization of `a`.

Comment: is there a way not using ostringstream? @user0042

Comment: @ArghavanM.hasani Well, there would be alternatives, to do that manually yourself, but why? That would be an idiomatic way to solve that problem in c++.

Comment: because iam writing this code for avr and i cant use all c++ libraries. @user0042

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @user0042

Comment: @geza thanks alot for your help

Comment: I've approved the edit, but it needs more votes

Comment: @geza Thanks a lot.